# How to prevent number being rounded to 0, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, average, formula

```
    public int total;
    public int likes;
    public double average;

    total = 5;
    likes = 21;

    average = likes / total;

    Log.d("Average", average);
```

Hi, `average = likes / total should` return 4.2, however, its running 4.0. How can I keep it as 4.2 and not 4.0?

Comment: Cast one of the variables as a double, otherwise it rounds down because integers are rounded.

Comment: Do you mean change total or likes to double? if so, I have tried that and it still returns 4.0

Comment: `average = (double)likes / total;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculations using only integers causes the **end result to be integer**, even if later you assign it to a floating point value like double. Integer division works by counting how many times the denominator can fit entirely in the numerator.

To resolve, you have to **cast at least one of the 2 operands** in the division so that the division is performed already in double precision (numbers inside arithmetic operations are automatically casted to a type that allow greater precision than its operands, if at least one of the operands have that precision):

```
average = (double)likes / total;
```

or

```
average = likes / (double) total;
```

Please note that this is different than `average = (double) (likes / total);`, which would cast the result after it has already been rounded down.

Comment: Thanks for the headup with the space in (double) :( I made that mistake

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a float? or should I convert double to float because I just found out I need the number to be a float

Comment: Possible also with `float`, yes.

Comment: Can you show me please I tried doing this (float) instead of (double) but it underlines in red

Comment: I want to get the value 4.2 but it rounding up if I convert double to float it gives 5

Comment: @JoshJoe Are you changing both the type of the variable `average` as well as the cast to `float`?

Comment: Yes, I only want the float for average

Comment: I took your code and changed `double` to `float` (`float average;` and `average = (float) likes / total;`) and it displays `4.2`. Did you change anything else?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote name of wrong variable. works now thanks.

Comment: upvooted for "Calculations using only integers causes the end result to be integer, even if later you assign it to a floating point value like double"

Answer (score 2):

```
average = (double)likes / total;
```

Comment: upvoted for shortness, but I fear someone could think that's a magic constant.

Comment: haha , right @DarioOO . Thanks for the vote though!

Comment: welcome :) @JoshJoe

Comment: AntonH asnwered it first so I had to accept his :) I did vote yours up but because I am under 15 rep it wont show

Comment: @JoshJoe  I answered first :) anyway no worries !!

Comment: he beat you to it in the comment answer :)

Comment: oh ! I just looked at the comment section :)

Comment: Is it possible to do this with a float? or should I convert double to float because I just found out I need the number to be a float

Comment: you can use float also  , float average = (float)likes / total;

Comment: Simple and accurate answer.. :)